# jsoup и html в java

Tags: java, jsoup

Есть такой код:

```
String url = "https://rozetka.com.ua/ua/notebooks/c80004/filter/";

Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements articles = document.select("article.pp-review-i");
Elements stars = articles.select("span.g-rating-stars-i");
Elements texts = articles.select("div.pp-review-text");
for(Element text:texts){
    System.out.println(text.text());
```

Но в итоге ничего не принтиться, хотя такие класи для таких атрибутов существуют. С java и jsoup только познакомился, и по тому, что я видел в интернете, вроде должно работать...

Comment: Мы не пойдём по левым ссылкам на подозрительные сайты чтобы пытаться понять какой именно кусок кода вам надо распарсить. Уберите ссылку и приведите проблемный кусок кода сайта - так можем помочь. В данный момент в вопросе нет самого важного

Comment: @ЮрийСПб кусок кода скинуть не могу, можете ввести rozetka, там вибрать ноутбуки, и будет нужная страница. Просто ето домашние задание, и бил аналог на пайтоне, и я не знаком с тем куском сайта, которий нужно парсить.

Comment: Вы всерьёз мне предлагаете сделать это за вас? Вроде же вам сайт то парсить... Идите на фриланс с таким подходом

Comment: Укажите UserAgent для начала, посмотрите закидывает ли сайт куки если да то сначала зайдите на главную подцепите куки и перейдите на интересующую вас страницу с куки и указав главную страницу как referrer

Answer (score 2):

На сайте есть проверка на бота. Видимо проверку не проходит.

Comment: Как я открыл страницу, запустилась капча.